# how to add an image programmatically from any url in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, product-images

I try this code but if the image doesn't exist in this path `pub/media/catalog/product`; it doesn't work. I want to `add an image` from any url; any ideas for that ?

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($productIds); $i++) {
                $productObj->load($productIds[$i]);
                //$productObj->addImageToMediaGallery('catalog/product/l/t/lt01.jpg', array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                $productObj->addImageToMediaGallery('catalog/product/'.$data['image'], array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                $productObj->save();
            }
```

Answer (score 12):

I assume that you’ve already **registered** your **extension** like `VendorName_ExtensionName` and it is located in the `app/code/VendorName/ExtensionName`. The code of the service:

```
<?php
/**
 * file location:
 * app/code/VendorName/ExtensionName/Service/ImportImageService.php
 */

namespace VendorName\ExtensionName\Service;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;

/**
 * Class ImportImageService
 * assign images to products by image URL
 */
class ImportImageService
{
    /**
     * Directory List
     *
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * File interface
     *
     * @var File
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * ImportImageService constructor
     *
     * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
     * @param File $file
     */
    public function __construct(
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        File $file
    ) {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Main service executor
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @param string $imageUrl
     * @param array $imageType
     * @param bool $visible
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function execute($product, $imageUrl, $visible = false, $imageType = [])
    {
        /** @var string $tmpDir */
        $tmpDir = $this->getMediaDirTmpDir();
        /** create folder if it is not exists */
        $this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
        /** @var string $newFileName */
        $newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($imageUrl);
        /** read file from URL and copy it to the new destination */
        $result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
        if ($result) {
            /** add saved file to the $product gallery */
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($newFileName, $imageType, true, $visible);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Media directory name for the temporary file storage
     * pub/media/tmp
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getMediaDirTmpDir()
    {

        return $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
...

use VendorName\ExtensionName\Service;
...
/**
* @var \VendorName\ExtensionName\Service\ImportImageService
*/
protected $importimageservice;

...

public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
\VendorName\ExtensionName\Service\ImportImageService $importimageservice
) {
$this->importimageservice = $importimageservice;
parent::__construct($context);
}

...

$imagePath = "http://test.img.png"; // path of the image
$this->importimageservice->execute($product, $imagePath, $visible = true, $imageType = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail']);
```

Comment: Why do  you use the folder `\Service`? I couldn't find its purpose anywhere.

Comment: @Kishan Patadia How to add external image URL for category.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279578/magento-2-import-categories-images-external-url-via-csv