# Magento 2.3.1 import images with external link still not working

Tags: import, product-images, csv, magento2.3.1

trying to pull image from external url during import but get:

```
"1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 2"
```

here is the link...
https://media.server.theshootingwarehouse.com/large/48217.jpg

I only have two products to test.. 
I exported products... edited the CSV to add the above url to the **base_image column.**

I have tried with and without **https:// 
I get the same errror.. I am on M2 2.3.1**

Comment: You can write something custom? This worked for me https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173440/70343

Comment: Isn't this supposed to be an option from native M2?  Why write custom code you have to maintain and keep current with M2 changes when the function is documented but just not functional (yet)?

Comment: True. I'm used to working to deadlines.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue!